# "Nós vamos se divertir" ou "Nós vamos nos divertir?"

Tags: gramática

Ouço constantemente na televisão o uso da palavra "se" em diversos tipos de frases, inclusive repetidas por apresentadores de TV. Qual a forma correta de dizer: "Nós vamos se divertir" ou "Nós vamos nos divertir"?

Comment: Se o pronome está no verbo divertir: "...nos divertir" ou "...divertirmo-nos"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em português europeu/de Portugal, não seria nenhuma das duas.

[Quando a locução verbal é composta por um verbo auxiliar e há occorência do infinitivo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/uso-dos-verbos-reflexivos-com-auxiliares/32683), pode ocorrer:

- ênclise ao verbo auxiliar: **`Nós vamo-nos divertir`** (que me parece que seria a expressão mais usada);
- ênclise ao infinitivo (que neste caso é o verbo principal): **`Nós vamos divertir-nos.`**

> (...) a ênclise é o padrão básico de colocação dos pronomes clíticos na variedade europeia do português moderno (...)
>
> (...) a ênclise é igualmente o padrão que se obtém em muitas frases não finitas [ou de infinitivo], em que o pronome clítico ocorre adjacente, respetivamente, a uma forma de infinitivo não flexionado, de infinitivo flexionado e de gerúndio (...) <sup><sup>[Mira Mateus et alii, Gramática da Língua Portuguesa, citado [nesta página](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-pronome-clitico-com-verbo-no-infinitivo-completiva-de-infinitivo/31702)]</sup></sup>

Parece haver algumas diferenças em relação ao português brasileiro e ao falado nas repúblicas africanas, no entanto, onde [a próclise ao verbo principal pode ser considerada uma característica destes dialectos](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ainda-a-proclise-a-mesoclise-e-a-enclise/27940), podendo portanto também dizer-se **`Nós vamos nos divertir`** nestes.

> A próclise é a regra no Brasil, enquanto, deste lado do Atlântico, “comanda” a ênclise. <sup><sup>[[fonte](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-proclise-e-a-enclise-em-portugal-e-no-brasil-novamente/21020)]</sup></sup>

Comment: A mim parece-me que como o pronome pessoal reflexo _nos_ se aplica ao verbo _divertir_, o mais correto seria escrever "vamos nos divertir" ou "vamos divertir-nos". No português falado a tendência está em relaxar esta regra, gerando ambiguidades. Mas vou consultar a gramática e já se fundamenta melhor.

Comment: Se o problema é o pronome pessoal reflexo _nos_ se aplicar sobre _divertir_ e não sobre _ir_, então parece-me que no português europeu só _vamos divertir-nos_ é que seria válido.

Comment: O verbo "ir" aqui é meramente auxiliar, e a meu bom entender não deverá receber o pronome.

Answer (score 9):

A forma correcta é *Nós vamos nos divertir* ou *Nós vamos divertir-nos* (sendo a última mais comum em Portugal). O motivo para isto é que o pronome que o verbo reflexivo necessita tem que concordar em número com o sujeito da frase.

Comment: "vamos nos" ou "vamo-nos"?

Comment: Qualquer uma; _Vamos nos_, indica que _nos_ pertence ao verbo que vem a seguir, mas _Vamos-nos_ também é correto.

Comment: Não me parece que esteja bem, mas não tenho a certeza por isso vou me remeter ao silêncio ;)

Comment: @someonewithpc *resposta

Comment: Mas, que eu saiba, nunca se usa _vamo**s**-nos_, mas sim _vamo-nos_.

Comment: @JNat Sim! Não sei como é que se me passou essa. Suponho que porque, pelo menos na minha região é comum dizer (erroneamente) _vamo**s** -nos_.